# Batch to force close all excel files

Tags: excel, batch-file

Is it possible to create a batch that forces all running instances of excel to close without saving any changes?

I ask because we have several `VB.net` programs and `VBA` programs that occasionally leave excel open (invisibly) when they error and these instances can interfere with future procedures and slow down performance.

Answer (score 13):

I suppose you might be able to do it using the [TaskKill](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb491009.aspx) tool with a syntax similar to:

```
taskkill /f /im Excel.exe
```

However, the proper solution would be to ask the developers of the VB.Net and VBA apps to close down Excel properly when they're finished with them (there are questions/answers here on SO describing how to make sure that it's closed down nicely if they don't know how).

Comment: +1 nice solution: Obviously the proper solution would be to close it properly, but say if user's have left Excel open before running the application, and it requires it to be closed as you cannot save data to an already opened spreadsheet.

Comment: +1...making sure no instances of excel linger running in the background is not a trivial matter - not sure if it is even possible to achieve using just `VBA` written from within `Excel` - it is definitely possible using a `.NET` application but even then is not trivial: therefore this answer is an excellent workaround.